# Duplicate Photoshop's "Color" blend mode in ImageMagick

Tags: imagemagick

I need to create a command that mimics Adobe Photoshop's "Color" blend mode in ImageMagick in order to tint an image. In order to do this, I'm trying to compose the original image and another image that consists of a full color layer, at 35% opacity. This should blend with the original image and create a color tinted result image.

This is the expected result:
[image: the expected result]

The "Color" blend mode is being defined, on the Adobe site, like this: "Creates a result color with the luminance of the base color and the hue and saturation of the blend color. This preserves the gray levels in the image and is useful for coloring monochrome images and for tinting color images."

There is a compose method defined into ImageMagick that seems to do the same thing (Luminize), but the results are not by far what is expected.

What seems to provide the closest result in Imagemagick is the default blend compose method, used like this:

```
convert image.jpg color_layer.png -compose blend -composite result.jpg
```

I also tried creating an image that would contain the luminosity of the first image and the hue and saturation of the second using the -fx operator, but the result was again nowhere near what I needed.

Comment: How are you accounting for the "35% opacity" in your ImageMagick commands?

Comment: In order to get that out of the way I created a transparent png file with the color and reduced the opacity to 35%. So, I'm practically trying to blend two existing image files.

Comment: Can you provide the following images: (1) original image; (2) color layer image at 35% opacity; (3) image of expected result (what photoshop creates)

Comment: I don't think it will work by blending the original image with a uniform red (semi-transparent at 35%) image. I think you need to extract the red channel from the original image, convert it to a ~35% transparent image and blend it with the original...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on Castles valuable answer, I tried to find the best solution of doing this in PHP. The  implementation he cited has two major flaws: one that it doesn't take account of the opacity, if any and the second that is very slow and resource consuming. Processing a 500x500 pixels image in PHP would take about 15 seconds in which Apache would hold the processor up to 95%.

The fastest and least resources consuming I found was actually doing it in HTML5 by using canvas to process the image. The results are amazing and the image is being processed on the spot.

I will post below the final chunks of code, one for PHP and one for HTML. If you need to use this serverside, you can copy-paste the HTML code in Node.js and NodeCanvas: https://github.com/LearnBoost/node-canvas

**PHP (with opacity):**

```
<?php

function Lum($colour) {
    return ($colour['r'] * 0.3) + ($colour['g'] * 0.59) + ($colour['b'] * 0.11);
}

function ClipColour($colour) {
    $result     = $colour;
    $luminance  = Lum($colour);

    $cMin = min($colour['r'], $colour['g'], $colour['b']);
    $cMax = max($colour['r'], $colour['g'], $colour['b']);

    if ($cMin < 0.0) {
        $result['r'] = $luminance + ((($colour['r'] - $luminance) * $luminance) / ($luminance - $cMin));
        $result['g'] = $luminance + ((($colour['g'] - $luminance) * $luminance) / ($luminance - $cMin));
        $result['b'] = $luminance + ((($colour['b'] - $luminance) * $luminance) / ($luminance - $cMin));
    } 

    if ($cMax > 255) {
        $result['r'] = $luminance + ((($colour['r'] - $luminance) * (255 - $luminance)) / ($cMax - $luminance));
        $result['g'] = $luminance + ((($colour['g'] - $luminance) * (255 - $luminance)) / ($cMax - $luminance));
        $result['b'] = $luminance + ((($colour['b'] - $luminance) * (255 - $luminance)) / ($cMax - $luminance));
    }

    return $result;
}

function SetLum($colour, $luminance) {

    $result = array();

    $diff =   $luminance - Lum($colour);

    $result['r'] = $colour['r'] + $diff;
    $result['g'] = $colour['g'] + $diff;
    $result['b'] = $colour['b'] + $diff;

    return ClipColour($result);

} 

function normalizeColor( $color ) {
    $color['r'] = $color['r'] / 255;
    $color['g'] = $color['g'] / 255;
    $color['b'] = $color['b'] / 255;

    return $color;
}

function denormalizeColor( $color ) {
    $color['r'] = round($color['r'] * 255);
    $color['g'] = round($color['g'] * 255);
    $color['b'] = round($color['b'] * 255);

    return $color;
}

$overlay_color = array('r'=>180,'g'=>22,'b'=>1, 'a' => 0.35);

$img = new Imagick();

if( !isset($_GET['case']) ) {
    $_GET['case'] = '';
}

//unmodified version
$original   = new Imagick('girl.jpg');

//photoshop image to compare
$ps = new Imagick('original.jpg');

$img->addImage($original);
$it = $original->getPixelIterator();

foreach( $it as $row => $pixels ) {
    foreach ( $pixels as $column => $pixel ) {
        $rgbIni = $pixel->getColor();

        $rgb = SetLum($overlay_color, Lum($rgbIni));
         $overlay_color     = normalizeColor($overlay_color);
            $rgb        = normalizeColor($rgb);

            $rgbIni         = normalizeColor($rgbIni);

        $rgb['r'] = ((1 - $overlay_color['a']) * $rgbIni['r']) + ($overlay_color['a'] * $rgb['r']);
        $rgb['g'] = ((1 - $overlay_color['a']) * $rgbIni['g']) + ($overlay_color['a'] * $rgb['g']);
        $rgb['b'] = ((1 - $overlay_color['a']) * $rgbIni['b']) + ($overlay_color['a'] * $rgb['b']);

        $test           = denormalizeColor($test);
        $rgb            = denormalizeColor($rgb);
        $overlay_color  = denormalizeColor($overlay_color);

        $pixel->setColor('rgb('.round($rgb['r']).','. round($rgb['g']).','.round($rgb['b']).')');

    }

    $it->syncIterator();
}

//add modified version
$img->addImage($original);
$img->addImage($ps);

$img->resetIterator();
$combined = $img->appendImages(true); //stack images

header('content-type: image/jpeg');

$combined->setImageFormat("jpeg");

echo $combined;

?>
```

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <script>
        var RGBA = function(r, g, b, a) {
            this.R = r || 0;
            this.G = g || 0;
            this.B = b || 0;
            this.A = a || 0.5;
        }

        function SetLum(initialColor, pixelColor) {

            var initalColorLuminance = initialColor.R * 0.3 + initialColor.G * 0.59 + initialColor.B * 0.11;
            var pixelColorLuminance = pixelColor.R * 0.3 + pixelColor.G * 0.59 + pixelColor.B * 0.11;

            var diff = pixelColorLuminance - initalColorLuminance;

            var response = new Array;
               response[0] = initialColor.R + diff;
               response[1] = initialColor.G + diff;
               response[2] = initialColor.B + diff;

            //console.log(response[0]);

            return ClipColour(response);

        }

        function alphaComposite(mv, ov, a) {
            return (mv * a) + (ov * (1 - a));
        }

        function ClipColour(color) { //function to prevent underexposure or overexposure on some pixels

            var result     = color;
            var luminance  = color[0] * 0.3 + color[1] * 0.59 + color[1] * 0.11;

            var cMin = Math.min(color[0], color[1], color[2]);
            var cMax = Math.max(color[0], color[1], color[2]);

            if (cMin < 0.0) {
                color[0] = luminance + (((color[0] - luminance) * luminance) / (luminance - cMin));
                color[1] = luminance + (((color[1] - luminance) * luminance) / (luminance - cMin));
                color[2] = luminance + (((color[2] - luminance) * luminance) / (luminance - cMin));
            } 

            if (cMax > 255) {
                color[0] = luminance + (((color[0] - luminance) * (255 - luminance)) / (cMax - luminance));
                color[1] = luminance + (((color[1] - luminance) * (255 - luminance)) / (cMax - luminance));
                color[2] = luminance + (((color[2] - luminance) * (255 - luminance)) / (cMax - luminance));
            }

            return color;
        }

        function processImage(image, targetColour) {
            var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
                c = canvas.getContext('2d');

            canvas.width = image.width;
            canvas.height = image.height;

            // Draw the building on the original canvas
            c.drawImage(image, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

            // There's a (much) faster way to cycle through all the pixels using typed arrays, 
            // but I'm playing it safe so that the example works in all browsers.
            var imageData = c.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height),
                imageDataPixels = imageData.data;

            for (var i = 0, len = imageDataPixels.length; i < len; i += 4) {
                var pixelColor = new RGBA(imageDataPixels[i], imageDataPixels[i+1], imageDataPixels[i+2], 1);
                var test = SetLum(targetColour, pixelColor);

                var r    = Math.round(test[0]);
                var g    = Math.round(test[1]);
                var b    = Math.round(test[2]);

                imageDataPixels[i] = alphaComposite(r, imageDataPixels[i], targetColour.A);
                imageDataPixels[i + 1] = alphaComposite(g, imageDataPixels[i + 1], targetColour.A);
                imageDataPixels[i + 2] = alphaComposite(b, imageDataPixels[i + 2], targetColour.A);
            }

            c.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);

            return canvas;
        }

        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
            var image = new Image(),
                processImageFile = null;

            image.src = "girl.jpg";

            image.addEventListener('load', function() {
                var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas'),
                    c = canvas.getContext('2d'),
                    imageRGBA = new RGBA(180, 22, 1, 0.35);

                canvas.width = image.width;
                canvas.height = image.height;

                c.drawImage(image, 0, 0);

                processImageFile = processImage(image, imageRGBA);
                c.drawImage(processImageFile, 0, 0);
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>

    <img src="girl.jpg" />
    <br />

    <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>

    <br />
    <img src="original.jpg" />
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

I've been trying to do this as well and the best I've come up with is use an overlay filter instead.. Here is my code in php:

```
$overlay_color = array('r'=>180,'g'=>22,'b'=>1);

function overlay ($top, $bottom) {
    return $bottom < 128 ? ( 2 * $bottom * $top ) / 255 : 255 - ( 2 * ( 255 - $bottom ) * ( 255 - $top ) / 255 );
}

$original = new Imagick('img/girl.jpg');

$img = new Imagick();

//unmodified version
$img->addImage($original);


$it = $original->getPixelIterator();

foreach( $it as $row => $pixels )
{
    foreach ( $pixels as $column => $pixel )
    {
            $rgba = $pixel->getColor();
            $pixel->setColor('rgb('.overlay($overlay_color['r'], $rgba['r']).','.overlay($overlay_color['g'], $rgba['g']).','.overlay($overlay_color['b'], $rgba['b']).')');
    }

    $it->syncIterator();
}

//add modified version
$img->addImage($original);


$img->resetIterator();
$combined = $img->appendImages(true); //stack images


header('content-type: image/jpeg');

$combined->setImageFormat("jpeg");

echo $combined;
```

I can't seem to find the formula for the Photoshop "color" mode. If I could find that it would be fairly straight forward.

Update: I found this site that explains the actual Photoshop formula fairly well: http://www.beneaththewaves.net/Photography/Secrets_of_Photoshops_Colour_Blend_Mode_Revealed_Sort_Of.html and I've managed to get it working in PHP. Here is the functions:

```
function Lum($colour) {

return ($colour['r'] * 0.3) + ($colour['g'] * 0.59) + ($colour['b'] * 0.11);

}



function ClipColour($colour) {

    $result = $colour;

    $luminance = Lum($colour);

    $cMin = min($colour['r'], $colour['g'], $colour['b']);

    $cMax = max($colour['r'], $colour['g'], $colour['b']);

    if ($cMin < 0.0) {

        $result['r'] = $luminance + ((($colour['r'] - $luminance) * $luminance) / ($luminance - $cMin));

        $result['g'] = $luminance + ((($colour['g'] - $luminance) * $luminance) / ($luminance - $cMin));

        $result['b'] = $luminance + ((($colour['b'] - $luminance) * $luminance) / ($luminance - $cMin));


    } 

    if ($cMax > 255) {

        $result['r'] = $luminance + ((($colour['r'] - $luminance) * (255 - $luminance)) / ($cMax - $luminance));

        $result['g'] = $luminance + ((($colour['g'] - $luminance) * (255 - $luminance)) / ($cMax - $luminance));

        $result['b'] = $luminance + ((($colour['b'] - $luminance) * (255 - $luminance)) / ($cMax - $luminance));

    }

    return $result;
}



function SetLum($colour, $luminance) {

    $result = array();

    $diff =   $luminance - Lum($colour);


    $result['r'] = $colour['r'] + $diff;

    $result['g'] = $colour['g'] + $diff;

    $result['b'] = $colour['b'] + $diff;


    return ClipColour($result);

}
```

and here is the updated pixel conversion code:

```
$rgb = $pixel->getColor();
$rgb = SetLum($overlay_color,Lum($rgb));
$pixel->setColor('rgb('.round($rgb['r']).','. round($rgb['g']).','.round($rgb['b']).')');
```

Comment: Hello Castles, this actually seems to do the trick for RGB images (no RGBA). I managed to add the transparency bit, too (my color has an alpha of 0.35). You can find the code here: http://pastebin.com/U1g5X16z. It seems that I had better results when I applied the transparency after I did the blending and not before. My logic would be that the transparency would need to be added before the actual blend. However, there is a huge problem with this code: it is really slow and it makes Apache use 99,5% of the processor while it's being ran.

Comment: I also translated this to Imagemagick, but the result is nowhere near what it should be. Maybe you have some ideas? 

convert original.jpg transparent_layer.png -channel RGBA -fx "diff=(u.r*0.3 + u.g*0.59 + u.b*0.11) - (v.r*0.3 + v.g*0.59 + v.b*0.11); v + diff" result.jpg

Note: Altoughe Imagemagick is capable of getting the luminance on its own, it doesn't use the same formula and you can't make the substraction because it throws an error